# Glide: try a second URL when the first fails to load

Tags: android, image

I'm using the following code:

```
        Glide
                .with(activity)
                .load(hdImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(250))
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(imageView);
```

HdImage is an URL string and could be invalid or empty, so I've set an error drawable.
But before showing it, i would like to try to load a second URL called, for example, sdImage.
Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kishan put me on the right path to find the solution. To try a second image if the first fails:

```
Glide
  .with(activity).load(hdImage)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
  .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(250))
  .error(
    Glide
      .with(activity)
      .load(sdImage)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
      .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(250))
      .error(R.drawable.error)
      )

  .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. This is in Kotlin. In onLoadFailed, you can try for sdImage URL.

```
Glide.with(activity).load(hdImage)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(250))
                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                    .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                            return false
                        }
                        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                           return false
                        }
                    })
                    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Thank you Kishan, unlukly this code throws a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can't start or clear loads in RequestListener or Target callbacks. If you're trying to start a fallback request when a load fails, use RequestBuilder#error(RequestBuilder). Otherwise consider posting your into() or clear() calls to the main thread using a Handler instead."
But it put me on the right path to find the solution.